how to get the balance out of my smart contract when the file is rewritten
I rewrite and recomplied the code file of my old smart contract because it doesn't allow me to withdraw, saying gas estimated failed. So I tried to rewrite the code and deploy again using the same file ( I didn't know I can't do this). How do I withdraw my balance now? I am so frustrated.

Can you provide more details about the contract? Once a contract has been deployed it cannot be modified, if the contract didn't have a withdraw functionality then the funds are forever locked.

If there's no function in the contract that allows you to withdraw funds, there's nothing you can do about it.
Please share the contract code.

I have a withdraw function, but it keeps telling me that Gas estimation failed and every time I withdraw, the transaction fails. Does it mean I can't do anything about it because I can't change the contract code anymore?
